# How to get remaining memory in system

Tags: c#, .net

My application(C#) takes around 2 and more GBs of RAM. How can I get available RAM in system so that I might be able to close my process if available RAM is below 20%.
I want to do this for windows machine.

Comment: System memory does not necessarily correlate with available memory

Comment: Also, your C# app will likely free up a lot of that memory if the system is under pressure. (Try minimizing the app and see if the memory usage drops; this is a coarse indicator of how much resource your app is keeping hold of just because there's no pressure to release it.)